How to get a scrolling effect and make a video appear
I would like to obtain a scrolling effect (from left to right) and have a video appear inside the div (not above or below) that plays.
This is the HTML and JQUERY code:


.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: #1b2522; 
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 1;
}

.left-side, .right-side {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.left-side p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin: 0;
}

.right-side img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover; 
}

button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

button img {
  width: 50px; 
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  background-color: #1b2522;
}

.video-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
   display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: #1b2522; 
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 1;
 
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
<div class="video-container">
  <video width="100%" height="100%" controls>
    <source src="https://onlinetestcase.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/1MB.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="left-side">
    <p>Where artisanal farming and the ecology stay strong</p>
  </div>

  <div class="center">
    <button id="toggle-button">
      <img src="piu.svg" alt="Play Button">
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="right-side">
    <img src="img/raccolto.jpg" alt="Immagine">
  </div>


</div>



I tried writing css and jquery code to achieve scrolling but I still have the problem that the video plays and appears at the top and never inside the div (with the same height and width dimensions). Please modify the code where necessary.

you want the effect to appear on page load, or sth else?
